# what is shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is that some thing like a programming language? Which does provide this option(facility) by a program running on linux or basic program that comes with linux kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell script is a program. Essentially, a user can execute a shell with a shell script as an argument. The shell will interpret the contents (a script language) and execute the listed commands in order from top to bottom.

For example, if you have bash shell (typically on linux and bsd systems) you could write a file called `hello-world.sh` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/env bash
# HelloWorld shell script

echo "Hello world $USER from $HOSTNAME"
```

You can then execute this script and it's contents will be interpreted. Lines beginning with a hash mark are comments. The third line simply echos text back on the command line using some common environment variables.

Then run the file like this:

```
localhost:~ ir0h$ sh hello-world.sh
```

Many facilities can be provided with this method. Typically, system administrators will use shell scripts to perform repetitive maintenance/tasks.